# Executing child (component) function from the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

To avoid this becoming messy and the use of "native" jQuery/javascript I would like to call a function in the child component from the parent, the function I want to exeecute is `change_map_data()` from the child `G_Map.vue` in an elegant way, vueish way:

Parent.vue

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-12">
    ...
    <i v-on:click="change_map_data">change markers</i>
    ...
    <g-map v-bind:map_data="init_data.map"></g-map>
    ...
</div>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            init_data: {
                map: {
                    map_ele: 'map'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</template>
```

G_Map.vue:

```
<template>
    <div :id="map_data.map_ele" class="gmap"></div>
</template>

<script>

import init_map from '../../../assets/js/map.js';

export default {

    props: ['map_data'],
    methods: {
        change_map_data: function() { // want to execute this from parent
            alert();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: To answer properly, we need to know what causes the parent to make this call. There is probably some state in the parent that changes; that state could be sent to the child, which would watch it.

Comment: @RoyJ, just a click, nothing has to change

Comment: I question the need for this; one of the strengths of frameworks like this is that you deal with actionable events via property changes. If nothing had to change them why do you need to call a child method?

Comment: @DaveNewton I think in this situation it would be better to eliminate the need to call `change_map_data()` on the child and just rely on the parent changing the bound `map_data` prop to change the map data (is this what you mean?). But there are some situations where you just want to make the child do something that has nothing to do with data binding at all.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Understood, but personally, I'd still rather trigger workout reaching into independent components-less hoops, and cleaner ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DecadeMoon I understand, but in this case it would be messy have all the methods (parent's and child's) in the parent, because I will have many child components (tables, charts, etc...) and all of them with specific methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a method defined on a child component from the parent component, you'll have to get a reference to the child component and call its method directly:

```
<i v-on:click="$refs.map.change_map_data()">change markers</i>
<g-map v-bind:map_data="init_data.map" ref="map"></g-map>
```

If you're generating a dynamic number of maps, then you'll need to do something like this:

```
<div v-for="map, i of maps">
  <i v-on:click="$refs.map[i].change_map_data()">change markers</i>
  <g-map v-bind:map_data="map" ref="map"></g-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. One question do I have to declare the functions `foo1` `foo2` in case I have two maps(same component) in the parent?

Comment: If you have 2 `<g-map>` components in the parent, then you'll have to give them each distinct `ref` values in order to distinguish between them in your code (e.g. `map1` and `map2`). The `foo` method in my answer doesn't mean anything, it's just an example of a method you can call which does something with the child component.

Comment: Ok, but do I have to make a function for each map (`map1` => `foo1()`, `map2` => `foo2`) or is there some other way to do it inside just `foo()`?